# Error on <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/> while publish on IIS

Tags: wcf, iis

I have one test wcf service with default methods and web config is :

```
 <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
</system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior>
                <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
</system.serviceModel>
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>
```

on local IIS it works fine when i publish it.But when i try to publish on remote IIS i am getting this error :

> Description: An error occurred during the processing of a
>   configuration file required to service this request. Please review the
>   specific error details below and modify your configuration file
>   appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as
>   allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This
>   error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an
>   application in IIS.
>
> ```
> Line 23:       </service>
> Line 24:     </services>
> **Line 25:        <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>**
> Line 26:  </system.serviceModel>
> Line 27:  <system.webServer>
> ```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the machine you are publishing to a different environment to the machine it works on. Make sure of the .NET Framework installed and IIS having the required settinsg

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I got the solution :

In IIS if the application is indeed an application, not a virtual directory? The icon should be something looks like the earth, not a folder's icon. If not, please convert it to an application right click on the folder select deploy and then Application.Service running with

Comment: It was working with virtual directory before, not sure what changed - may be some .net features we are using needed our virtual directory as "Application". Thanks for solution

Comment: How do you tell which virtual directory should be an application in the IIS?

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you browse to the actual web folder (that contains `Bin`, `*.svc` and `web.config`) when creating web application, not the parent folder.

Answer (score -3):

If you working  framework 4.0  only one ENDpoint so write multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="False"
serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="False"

Using this it will be run