# Error: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, web-config

I am getting below error in my WCF application, it is working when I am running on my local machine (visual studio) but getting an error when it's deployed on IIS:

```
Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.

Source File: D:\Site\Website\service\web.config   Line:52
```

My web.config code on line:52

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment  aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Learn some basics about IIS/IIS Express, and then you know it https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/understanding-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-on-iis

Answer (score 0):

There might be something wrong with the type of website in IIS. The website’s icon should be a website instead of a folder icon. Please convert it to an application, right-click on the folder and select deploy.
Please refer to the below link for details.
[Error on <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/> while publish on IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9905911/error-on-servicehostingenvironment-multiplesitebindingsenabled-true-while-p)
Here are some related links, wish it is useful to you.
[https://forums.asp.net/t/2036852.aspx?Configuration+Error](https://forums.asp.net/t/2036852.aspx?Configuration%20Error)
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/dbc040c1-3294-45bd-b8eb-2b38a884625b/in-vs-2013-im-getting-the-allowdefinitionmachinetoapplication-error-after-taking-over-project?forum=msbuild
Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.